# Aggregating names of multiple list elements into a single array with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I have some lists I'm allowing to be rearranged with sortable.js and I need to create an array of the sort order on drag completion. The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="catscontainer">
    <div id="parentcat1" class="parentcatcontainer">
    <h4 class="parentcathead">Parent Category One</h4>
    <ul class="subcatlist" id="ul-parentcat1">
        <li id="parentcat1-subcat1">Sub Category One</li>
        <li id="parentcat1-subcat2">Sub Category Two</li>
        <li id="parentcat1-subcat3">Sub Category Three</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="parentcat2" class="parentcatcontainer">
    <h4 class="parentcathead">Parent Category Two</h4>
    <ul class="subcatlist" id="ul-parentcat2">
        <li id="parentcat2-subcat1">Sub Category One</li>
        <li id="parentcat2-subcat2">Sub Category Two</li>
        <li id="parentcat2-subcat3">Sub Category Three</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I had been using the following sortable code:

```
var sortySubCats = Sortable.create(el, {
    group: 'titles',
    animation: 150,
    dataIdAttr: 'id',
    onUpdate: function( /**Event*/ evt) {
        var orderListSub = sortySubCats.toArray();
    }
}
```

Which led to an array, `orderListSub`, that only outputs a list of the items in the parent category just interacted with. This is fine but doesn't suit my purposes. In mySQL I store a serialised version of an array of the entire hierarchy. The structure is superfluous for this question but I do need to output the following in order after completion of each drag:

```
Parent Category ID
> Sub Category ID
> Sub Category ID
> Sub Category ID
Parent Category ID
> Sub Category ID
> Sub Category ID
> Sub Category ID
etc...
```

into an array that I can serialise. Currently I am looking at iterating through each UL of the catscontainer div for id names, and sub-iterating inside this for LI id names. This should return them in order. Is there a particularly clean way of doing so through jquery or does sortable actually have this functionality better implemented than I've experienced?

---

**Update:**

I've gone with the following simple jquery to capture the ids of the parent and child elements of the list in the order that matches their appearance after dragging. Seems to be the most straightforward way and I can add some more code to turn it into the array I need. I'll add this as the answer if there's no better suggestions.

```
function catsToArrayJSON() { // called after drag complete
    $("#catscontainer ul").each(function () {
        console.log('Parent is: ' + this.id);
        $(this).children("li").each(function () {
            console.log('Child is: ' + this.id);
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone with the following simple jquery to capture the ids of the parent and child elements of the list in the order that matches their appearance after dragging. Seems to be the most straightforward way and I can add some more code to turn it into the array I need.

```
function catsToArrayJSON() { // called after drag complete
    $("#catscontainer ul").each(function () {
        console.log('Parent is: ' + this.id);
        $(this).children("li").each(function () {
            console.log('Child is: ' + this.id);
        })
    });
}
```